# Firebase: block spam users in anonymous mode - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase database and offer anonymous login. for strangers chat application, is it possible to report anonymous spammers? and block them of using the service? is it going to be by device number or something else?

What i'm trying / thinking to do is to make a report button, if user got 20 flags then the user will permanent suspended, or suspended for a couple of hours. from using the service.

which data are possible to collect from users in anonymous mode? so we can use to achieve reporting / blocking system?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: If you suspect your project is a target of abuse, please contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: No i don't, still in progress project.

Comment: Keep that in mind if and when you begin to collect evidence.  Until there, I suspect there's not much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed you can.
Have every user with a database reference eg: users/userUID/flags. This will allow you to add the flags if the user is flagged. When this count reaches your desired value. You can then change their layout to may be a text saying "blocked" or hide the text inputs. 
In as much as you do this, they can simply create a new account since its anonymous log in

Answer (score 0):

yes,i did in a way similar,every anon user have a specific id when they register,the way i did it.

when user report another users,i store the info as this report/userids/userswhoreportid with a value of 1,

why use reporter users id?

to make sure each user can report a user one,also you can know if they reported the user before,
how to know when users reports reached 20?

observesingleevet of report/userids and get child count if its >= 20 then users should be blocked.

why i recommend another node using reports/userids/flags other than users/userids/flags

?

well because when reading data from users/userids you will also read flags which sometime arent necessory.